# XML - add a namespace not in root

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I need to build XML in SQL Server that has this format. You can see there are two XMLNAMESPACES on the first line but there is a third one further down next to Location.

```
<arrayofstuff xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes">
  <stuff>
    <Description>blue</Description>
    <Location xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Infrastructure.CodeValues">
      <d3p1:Code>64</d3p1:Code>
      <d3p1:Description>Balloons</d3p1:Description>
    </Location>
  </stuff>
</arrayofstuff>
```

Here is what I have so far, with some sample data. It looks like there is a nested for XML query within the first query, but I can't seem to use the WITH statement a second time since it has to be the first command in a batch, so I'm not sure what to do.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('myTable'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [myTable];
END;
GO

CREATE TABLE [myTable] (
    [myTableID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Description] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [sourceID] INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    [Location] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Code] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Location_Desc] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([myTableID])
);
GO

INSERT INTO myTable([SourceID],[Description],[Location],[Code],[Location_Desc])
VALUES(3,'yellow','Oxford County','64','list'),
(3,'blue','Fraser Lake','64','list'),
(2,'red','San Marcello Pistoiese','64','list'),
(2,'green','Gembloux','64','list'),
(2,'green','Yeongcheon','64','list')

GO

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Domain.Core.ComplexTypess', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i )
SELECT 
[sourceID]
,cast(stuff((
 SELECT
[Description] as [Description]
,[Code] AS [Location/Code]
,[Location_Desc] AS [Location/Description]
FROM [myTable] mnbm
where mnbm.[sourceID] = p.[sourceID]
for xml path('stuff'), root ('arrayofstuff')
),1,0,'') as xml) as Ids
from [myTable]  p
group by 
p.[sourceID]
```

Here is the result of my output currently:

```
<arrayofstuff xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Domain.Core.ComplexTypess">
  <stuff>
    <Description>commodo</Description>
    <Location>San Marcello Pistoiese</Location>
  </stuff>
  <stuff>
    <Description>ipsum</Description>
    <Location>Gembloux</Location>
  </stuff>
  <stuff>
    <Description>ipsum</Description>
    <Location>Yeongcheon</Location>
  </stuff>
</arrayofstuff>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there some specific reason why `xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Infrastructure.CodeValues"` has to appear on the Location element? Namespaces can be defined anywhere in an XML document, so long as they're defined before they're referenced, so you can define it on the root element as part of `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, e.g.:

```sql
drop table if exists dbo.myTable;

create table dbo.myTable (
    myTableID integer not null identity(1, 1),
    [Description] varchar(max) null,
    sourceID integer not null,
    [Location] varchar(255) null,
    Code varchar(255) null,
    Location_Desc varchar(255) null,
    primary key (myTableID)
);

insert into dbo.myTable (sourceID,[Description],[Location],Code,Location_Desc)
values (1, 'blue', 'Somewhere', '64', 'Balloons');

with xmlnamespaces (
    default 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Domain.Core.ComplexTypess',
    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Infrastructure.CodeValues' as d3p1,
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i )
select
    [sourceID],
    cast((
        select
            [Description],
            Code as [Location/d3p1:Code],
            Location_Desc as [Location/d3p1:Description]
        from dbo.myTable mnbm
        where mnbm.sourceID = p.sourceID
        for xml path('stuff'), root('arrayofstuff')
    ) as xml) as Ids
from dbo.myTable p
group by p.sourceID;
```

Which yields:

```xml
<arrayofstuff
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Infrastructure.CodeValues"
  xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Domain.Core.ComplexTypess">
  <stuff>
    <Description>blue</Description>
    <Location>
      <d3p1:Code>64</d3p1:Code>
      <d3p1:Description>Balloons</d3p1:Description>
    </Location>
  </stuff>
</arrayofstuff>
```

Comment: The reason for the namespace being defined in the location tag is simply that that is what the application I'm working with does and so I assumed that I needed to do that. I will test what you are suggesting,that would be great if that's all it takes.

Comment: The application did take it the way that was suggested just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution based on XQuery and FLWOR expression.

It is producing XML that is shaped exactly as the desired output.

It is a two step process:

1. Compose raw XML.
2. Shape raw XML with namespaces based on the desired output.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    [myTableID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Description] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [sourceID] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [Location] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Code] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Location_Desc] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([myTableID])
);

INSERT INTO @myTable
(
    [sourceID],
    [Description],
    [Location],
    [Code],
    [Location_Desc]
)
VALUES
(3, 'yellow', 'Oxford County', '64', 'list'),
(3, 'blue', 'Fraser Lake', '64', 'list'),
(2, 'red', 'San Marcello Pistoiese', '64', 'list'),
(2, 'green', 'Gembloux', '64', 'list'),
(2, 'green', 'Yeongcheon', '64', 'list');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT [sourceID]
        , (SELECT [Description] AS [Description]
            , [Code] AS [Code]
            , [Location_Desc] AS [Location_Desc]
            FROM @myTable AS mnbm
            WHERE mnbm.[sourceID] = p.[sourceID]
            FOR XML PATH('stuff'), TYPE, ROOT('arrayofstuff')
        ) AS Ids
    FROM @myTable AS p
    GROUP BY p.[sourceID]
)
SELECT rs.sourceID, rs.Ids AS [Before]
    , rs.Ids.query('<arrayofstuff xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes">
{
    for $x in /*:arrayofstuff/*:stuff
    return <stuff>
        <Description>{data($x/*:Description)}</Description>
        <Location xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Infrastructure.CodeValues">
            <d3p1:Code>{data($x/*:Code)}</d3p1:Code>
            <d3p1:Description>{data($x/*:Location_Desc)}</d3p1:Description>
        </Location>
    </stuff>
}
</arrayofstuff>') AS [After]
FROM rs;
```